# My wifi doesn't work after I switch from Windows to Ubuntu. I can connect, but there is no internet

Tags: wireless, internet

My wifi only works occasionally, it seems to be worst when I'm coming off my Windows boot and going straight to Ubuntu. Most every morning, it works perfectly fine. In my Windows installation, I usually have to turn off the wireless adapter before it works, but that trick does not work in Ubuntu. I'm running 12.04 LTS, 32 bit. These are my ifconfig and netstat data:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:9d:41:13  
      inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4a5d:60ff:fe9d:4113/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2804 (2.8 KB)  TX bytes:24647 (24.6 KB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Comment: Do you press "restart" or "shutdown" when you want to move to Ubuntu from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks quite fine so far.

Question: did you set up your wifi-connection correctyl in network-manager in Ubuntu??
Question: did a notice show up on your screen saying "wireless networks available" after booting into Ubuntu??

If so, then your connection is not set up correctly in your network-manager in Ubuntu.

To set up your wifi-connection-correctly, go to your menue.
In your menue, select system-preferences.
In the system-preferences, select network-connections.

There enter all your data (including your wifi-key). And do not forget to check these both options on the very first window in network-manager:

"automaticly connect to this network, if present".
"allow all users to use this network".

These both options need to be checked.

Then on the top, you need to set up a name for your connection. For example "connection  (here replace these brackets with your own name!!)

Then in the second window, select IP4 and enter your wlan-key.

In the third window with IPv6 select "ignore".

Save these changes and close network-manager.

Return back to your panel and click the nm-applet. Then it should see your network.
Select your network. Then it should connect automaticly.

Greetings
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact cause, but restarting router solves this issue for me.

*Rebooting to Windows from Ubuntu works fine and internet is accessible but after rebooting back to Ubuntu from Windows, even if the network indicator shows connected to WiFi, internet is not accessible.*